# Converting elements in multiple variables by for loop is not working

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-for-loop

I have ran code to save names of variables which are character and binary in object binvar

```
print(binvar)
```

[1] "x1"     "x2" "x3"            "x4"
[5] "x5"

I want to use this to select columns in my the original dataframe df in order to run a for loop where I convert yes and no to 1 and 0.

```
for(i in 1:length(binvar)){
  for(j in 1:length(nrow(df))){
    if(df[[binvar[i]]][j]=="Yes"){
      df[[binvar[i]]][j]<-1
    }
    else if(df[[binvar[i]]][j]=="No"){
      df[[binvar[i]]][j]<-0
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the loop doesn't iterate over all elements inside the selected columns but only on the first element of each column. I thought iterator j would go over all element.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need a nested loop in `R`.  The `==` is elementwise comparison operator.  Subset the dataset ('df') based on the vector of column names ('binvar') i.e. `df[binvar]`), create a logical matrix (`== "Yes"`) and coerce the logical to binary (`+`) and assign (`<-`) back to the subset of columns (assuming there are only 'Yes', 'No' and possibly NA)

```
df[binvar] <- +(df[binvar] == "Yes")
```

---

In the OP's nested loop, the second expression is the problematic because `nrow` returns a single value and the `length` will be 1, so `1:1` is always 1.

```
for(j in 1:length(nrow(df)))
```

It should be

```
for(j in seq_len(nrow(df)))
```

If we want a reproducible example

```
> data(iris)
> nrow(iris)
[1] 150
> length(nrow(iris))
[1] 1
> 1:length(nrow(iris))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Indeed, ```for(j in 1:length(nrow(df)))``` was the problem.
Because ```1:length(nrow(df))``` returns just ## 1

Changing it to ```for(j in 1:(nrow(df)))``` was sufficient to solve the problem.

Also thank you for the input on the better method

Comment: @Aspiranto Just to be bug free, it would use `seq_len` instead of `1:` because some cases it is possible to return a data.frame with 0 row, then 1:0 returns 1